# Drag down formula and change ROW references instead of COLUMNS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rows, drag

In excel I have `sheet1` contains total every month. *(please see image below)*

[image]

Then in my `sheet2` it will display horizontally. *(please see image below)*

[image]

I used the formula `=Sheet1!$B$1`, my problem is when i drag it to the right it increments the column letters. How should i make it increment the row only and the column letter is constant in column "**B**".

Any ideas and alternatives is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the title makes no sense. If you drag a formula up/down it will change **row** references. It is when you drag a formula across,then it will change **columns**..  It looks like you want to drag your formula to the right and change rows

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use OFFSET:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,COLUMN()-2,0)
```

Or TRANSPOSE:  Select B2:M2 and then enter

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!$B$1:B12)
```

as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)